# I got "Null value specified for an a null attribute" this error

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public class BuildGraph1 {  
  // Members of the House to be inserted in the database
  final static Object houseMemberData[][] = {
        // memberName, crownName, houseHead, yearBorn, yearDied, reignStart, reignEnd, crownTitle
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", null, false, 1746, 1785, null, null, null },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", null, false, 1750, 1836, null, null, null },
        { "Joseph Bonaparte", "Joseph I", false, 1768, 1844, "6 Jun 1808", "11 Dec 1813", "King of Spain" },
        { "Napoleon Bonaparte", "Napoleon I", false, 1769, 1821, "18 May 1804", "22 Jun 1815", "Emperor of the French" },
        { "Lucien Bonaparte", null, false, 1775, 1840, null, null, null },
        { "Elisa Bonaparte", "Elisa Bonaparte", false, 1777, 1820, "3 Mar 1809", "1 Feb 1814", "Grand Duchess of Tuscany" },
        { "Louis Bonaparte", "Louis I", false, 1778, 1846, "5 Jun 1806", "1 Jul 1810", "King of Holland" },
        { "Pauline Bonaparte", null, false, 1780, 1825, null, null, null },
        { "Caroline Bonaparte", null, false, 1782, 1839, null, null, null },
        { "Jerome Bonaparte", "Jerome I", false, 1784, 1860, "8 Jul 1807", "26 Oct 1813", "King of Westphalia" },
        { "Marie Louise of Austria", null, false, 1791, 1847, null, null, "Empress Consort of the French" },
        { "Josephine of Beauharnais", null, false, 1763, 1814, null, null, "Empress Consort of the French" },
        { "Alexandre of Beauharnais", null, false, 1760, 1794, null, null, null },
        { "Betsy Patterson", null, false, 1785, 1879, null, null, null },
        { "Catharina of Wurttemberg", null, false, 1783, 1835, null, null, "Queen Consort of Westphalia" },
        { "Francois Bonaparte", "Napoleon II", false, 1811, 1832, "22 Jun 1815", "7 Jul 1815", "Emperor of the French" },
        { "Hortense of Beauharnais", null, false, 1783, 1837, null, null, "Queen Consort of Holland" },
        { "Jerome Napoleon", null, false, 1805, 1870, null, null, null },
        { "Prince Napoleon", null, false, 1822, 1891, null, null, null },
        { "Louis Napoleon", "Napoleon III", true, 1808, 1873, "2 Dec 1852", "4 Sep 1870", "Emperors of the French" },
        { "Napoleon-Louis Bonaparte", "Louis II", false, 1804, 1831, "1 Jul 1810", "13 Jul 1810", "King of Holland" },
        { "Napoleon IV Eugene", null, true, 1856, 1879, null, null, null },
        { "Napoleon V Victor", null, true, 1862, 1926, null, null, null },
        { "Marie Clotilde Bonaparte", null, false, 1912, 1996, null, null, null },
        { "Napoleon VI Louis", null, true, 1914, 1997, null, null, null },
        { "Napoleon VII Charles", null, true, 1950, null, null, null, null },
        { "Napoleon VIII Jean-Christophe", null, true, 1986, null, null, null, null },
        { "Sophie Catherine Bonaparte", null, false, 1992, null, null, null, null } 
  };

  // Relation among the members of the House to be inserted in the database
  final static Object houseRelationData[][] = {
        // memberName, memberName, relType
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Letizia Ramolino", "spouse" }, 
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Joseph Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", "Joseph Bonaparte", "child" }, 
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Napoleon Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", "Napoleon Bonaparte", "child" }, 
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Lucien Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", "Lucien Bonaparte", "child" }, 
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Elisa Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", "Elisa Bonaparte", "child" }, 
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Louis Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", "Louis Bonaparte", "child" }, 
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Pauline Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", "Pauline Bonaparte", "child" }, 
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Caroline Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", "Caroline Bonaparte", "child" }, 
        { "Carlo Bonaparte", "Jerome Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Letizia Ramolino", "Jerome Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Napoleon Bonaparte", "Marie Louise of Austria", "spouse" },
        { "Napoleon Bonaparte", "Francois Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Marie Louise of Austria", "Francois Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Napoleon Bonaparte", "Josephine of Beauharnais", "spouse" },
        { "Alexandre of Beauharnais", "Josephine of Beauharnais", "spouse" },
        { "Alexandre of Beauharnais", "Hortense of Beauharnais", "child" },
        { "Josephine of Beauharnais", "Hortense of Beauharnais", "child" },
        { "Louis Bonaparte", "Hortense of Beauharnais", "spouse" },
        { "Louis Bonaparte", "Louis Napoleon", "child" },
        { "Hortense of Beauharnais", "Louis Napoleon", "child" },
        { "Louis Bonaparte", "Napoleon-Louis Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Hortense of Beauharnais", "Napoleon-Louis Bonaparte", "child" },
        { "Jerome Bonaparte", "Betsy Patterson", "spouse" },
        { "Jerome Bonaparte", "Jerome Napoleon", "child" },
        { "Betsy Patterson", "Jerome Napoleon", "child" },
        { "Jerome Bonaparte", "Catharina of Wurttemberg", "spouse" },
        { "Jerome Bonaparte", "Prince Napoleon", "child" },
        { "Catharina of Wurttemberg", "Prince Napoleon", "child" },
        { "Louis Napoleon", "Napoleon IV Eugene", "child" },
        { "Prince Napoleon", "Napoleon V Victor", "child" },
        { "Napoleon V Victor", "Napoleon VI Louis", "child" },
        { "Napoleon VI Louis", "Napoleon VII Charles", "child" },
        { "Napoleon VII Charles", "Napoleon VIII Jean-Christophe", "child" },
        { "Napoleon VII Charles", "Sophie Catherine Bonaparte", "child" } };

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "tcp://localhost:8228";
    String user = "napoleon";
    String pwd = "bonaparte";
    TGConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = TGConnectionFactory.getInstance().createConnection(url, user, pwd, null);
        conn.connect();

        TGGraphObjectFactory gof = conn.getGraphObjectFactory();
        if (gof == null) {
            throw new Exception("Graph object not found");
        }

        TGGraphMetadata gmd = conn.getGraphMetadata(true);
        TGNodeType houseMemberType = gmd.getNodeType("houseMemberType");
        if (houseMemberType == null)
            throw new Exception("Node type not found");
        TGNode houseMember;
        Hashtable<String, TGNode> houseMemberTable = new Hashtable<String, TGNode>();

        //
        // Insert node data into database
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < houseMemberData.length; i++) {
            houseMember = gof.createNode(houseMemberType);
            houseMember.setAttribute("memberName", houseMemberData[i][0]);
            houseMember.setAttribute("crownName", houseMemberData[i][1]);
            houseMember.setAttribute("houseHead", houseMemberData[i][2]);
            houseMember.setAttribute("yearBorn", houseMemberData[i][3]);
            houseMember.setAttribute("yearDied", houseMemberData[i][4]);
            houseMember.setAttribute("crownTitle", houseMemberData[i][7]);

            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (houseMemberData[i][5] != null) {
                date.setTime((new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse((String) houseMemberData[i][5])));
                houseMember.setAttribute("reignStart", date);
            }
            else 
                houseMember.setAttribute("reignStart", null);

            if (houseMemberData[i][6] != null) {
                date.setTime((new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse((String) houseMemberData[i][6])));
                houseMember.setAttribute("reignEnd", date);
            }
            else 
                houseMember.setAttribute("reignEnd", null);

            conn.insertEntity(houseMember);
            conn.commit(); // Write data to database
            System.out.println(
                    "Transaction completed for Node : " + houseMember.getAttribute("memberName").getAsString());
            houseMemberTable.put(houseMember.getAttribute("memberName").getAsString(), houseMember);
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

        // 
        // Insert edge data into database
        // 
        TGNode houseMemberFrom;
        TGNode houseMemberTo;
        TGEdge houseRelation;
        TGEdge.DirectionType houseRelationDirection;
        for (int i = 0; i < houseRelationData.length; i++) {
            houseMemberFrom = houseMemberTable.get(houseRelationData[i][0]);
            houseMemberTo = houseMemberTable.get(houseRelationData[i][1]);
            houseRelationDirection = houseRelationData[i][2].equals("spouse") ? TGEdge.DirectionType.UnDirected
                    : TGEdge.DirectionType.Directed;
            houseRelation = gof.createEdge(houseMemberFrom, houseMemberTo, houseRelationDirection);
            houseRelation.setAttribute("relType", houseRelationData[i][2]);
            conn.insertEntity(houseRelation);
            conn.commit();
            System.out.println(
                    "Transaction completed for Edge : " + houseMemberFrom.getAttribute("memberName").getAsString()
                            + " to " + houseMemberTo.getAttribute("memberName").getAsString());
        }
        System.out.println("\nHouse of Bonaparte graph completed successfully");
    } 
    finally {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

I got following Exception:

> INFO: Hand shake successfull. Nov 11, 2016 10:16:38 AM
>   com.tibco.tgdb.log.SimpleJavaLogger log INFO: Connected successfully
>   using user:napoleon Exception in thread "main"
>   com.tibco.tgdb.exception.TGException: Null value specified for an a
>   null attribute    at
>   com.tibco.tgdb.model.impl.AbstractEntity.setAttribute(AbstractEntity.java:102)
>     at com.tibco.tgdb.example.BuildGraph1.main(BuildGraph1.java:151)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `for loop` in `main` method, you are calling `setAttribute()` with `null` value for `"crownName"`
You array `houseMemberData` has null values for `"crownName"`